# How to update ios table view after deleting child from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having difficulty getting my `tableview` to reload after executing `removeValue()` from my **firebase**. The table only updates if I exit and come back to the page, which is not my intent. I would like to have the table be updated real time as posts are deleted. Seeking advice how can I achieve that.

I have tried adding the following to my code but it doesn't work.

```
postsDB.observe(.childRemoved) { (snapshot) in
    self.myPostsTable.reloadData() 
}
```

My firebase structure looks like this:

[image]

I'm using **SwipeCellKit Pod**, and my code for deleting a post is as such:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) ->
 [SwipeAction]? {

    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in
        let postsDB = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        let selectedPost = self.postArray[indexPath.row]
        let postid = selectedPost.postid
        postsDB.child(postid).removeValue()

    }
    configure(action: delete, with: .trash)
    return [delete]      
}
```

Comment: Supply details what is not called or why the update does not happen. Is `postsDB.observe()`'s block not called for example?

Comment: I have tried adding breakpoints and verified all of the code were called. I'm not sure why the table doesn't reload, hence seeking advice if there's some other code I need to add to make it work.

Comment: @Ben I think you forgot to remove the data from array. Or if you removing the object from firebase then you need to reload the tableview.

Comment: You need to refer to your `UITableViewDataSource` functions (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection`) and perform any _local_ data changes so that the table view is reloaded properly. I assume you have some array of data that you're fetching from Firebase? You'd want to remove the item for that row.

Comment: Yes I am removing from Firebase. How do I reload the tableview? I used an observe(.childRemoved) but it doesn't work. Is that the right way to reload the table?

Comment: @Connor, could you elaborate a little on what local changes do I need to execute? I had thought that as soon as the child is removed from firebase the tableview would update...

Comment: What does your `numberOfRowsInSection` look like?

Comment: @connor,  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postArray.count
    }

Comment: So you need to remove the relevant item from `postArray`.

Comment: yup i got it, thanks a lot Connor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when working with a database and without a controller like `NSFetchedResultsController` you have to delete an item in three steps

1. Remove the item from the database.
2. Remove the item from the data source array.
3. Delete the row in the table view.

So you have to add the steps 2 und 3

```
let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in
      let postsDB = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
      let selectedPost = self.postArray[indexPath.row]
      let postid = selectedPost.postid
      postsDB.child(postid).removeValue()
      self.postArray.remove(at: indexPath.row) // step 2
      self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) // step 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine! This seems to perform the data changes locally. Is there an alternative way to update the table based on changes in firebase, like using an observer?

Comment: Yes, update the UI in the completion handler of the observer.

Comment: Is this not the right code for the completion handler of childRemoved observer?  postsDB.observe(.childRemoved) { (snapshot) in
self.myPostsTable.reloadData() }

Comment: Yes, it is,and it's always better to remove a single row rather than to reload the entire table. The only requirement is the index (path).

Comment: Thanks a lot folks!